# Insert JSON into Riak via curl

Tags: json, curl, riak

I have JSON:

```
{
   title: "Some title",
   author: "Name",
   text: "This is text..."
}
```

that I want to store to my Riak via curl.I'm using command:

```
curl -v -X PUT http://192.168.56.12:10018/riak/news/news1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"title":"Some title","author":"Name","text":"This is text..."}"
```

And when I try to see what's in the bucket called news with key news1 via Firefox I get only: `{title:Some`

What is not correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument to `-d` should be in single quotes:

`-d '{"title":"Some.....}'`

Comment: thx, now i get '{title:Some title,author:Name,text:This is text...}'. JSON values are not in "" so will they be decoded as strings?

Comment: Luke's example is missing a closing double quote on the value, maybe you replicated this? Otherwise depending on how you're using the returned JSON you may need to backslash escape the double quotes before storing, `'{title: \"Some title\", ... }'`